# How to see the full command used to run a container in a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In Docker we can see the full command used to run a container using

```
docker ps --no-trunc
```

In case of containers inside pods in a Kubernetes cluster, how to find this same info?

I also tried to describe a pod using `kubectl describe pods test-77f45b7bd7-hqvqh -n somenp` but it doesn't show that information:

```
Containers:
  data-exploration:
    Container ID:   docker://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Image:          docker_uri
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://docker_uri
    Port:           3002/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 22 Dec 2023 10:37:25 +0000
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  5Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     500m
      memory:  1Gi
    Environment:
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes by default runs the command specified in container image. You can override that command using `command` and `args` in pod spec (see [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod)).

So the only way to find the command is either to exec into the pod or inspect the container image.